# Onion Skin is hidden behind Grease Pencil layers, how do I show onion skin in front of the other layers?

Tags: grease-pencil

I haven't been able to find an answer for this anywhere. Windows 11, Blender 3.5.0, question is the title: I have onion skin activated in the 3D viewport, and I can see the onion skins, but the problem is that they are hidden by the actual artwork - lines and fills cover up the onion skins.

Reducing opacity doesn't work either because that reduces the opacity of onion skins for that layer. My startup file has the same issue. Is there any way to make onion skins show above grease pencil artwork?